# Is window.navigator.userAgent really going to be deprecated?

Tags: javascript

I just [read on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent) about window.navigator.userAgent:

> Deprecated 
>   This feature has been removed from the Web standards.
>   Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of
>   being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps
>   using it may break at any time.

I am not finding any other significant reference on the web confirming this statement. User agent information are widely used by many companies for various reasons (analytics, bug fixes in specific browser ...). While I understand that one should use feature detection over ua sniffing it just seems incredible that this information would go away.

Is it really going away or is it just a Mozilla thing?

If so, is there a replacement for it?

Comment: "If so, is there a replacement for it?" — There's a big See Also section in the document you link to.

Comment: Yes thanks I read it. It does not answer my question.

Comment: One of them is "Use feature oriented object detection"

Comment: "Browser identification (aka "browser sniffing"): not best, not reliable approach" — covers it too

Comment: This is not the point of my question. I know and use feature detection. My question is about the user agent information.

Comment: You asked if there was a replacement for a feature used for user agent detection. There is. It is feature detection. That has been the recommended approach to the problem for almost two decades.

Comment: It's not going to be deprecated, it **is** deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

The deprecation notice seems to be gone now. It was removed [yesterday](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent$revision/1238825), over a year after this question was first asked, with the following comment:

> rm deprecation marker. This is not removed from the living spec and no deprecation either. Most use cases are discouraged for quality reasons, but that's something else.

The [WHATWG Living standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-navigator-useragent) hasn't deprecated this property, so that confirms that the property *isn't* going away. Sure, it's a crapshoot and easily spoofed, but "not recommended for use" is not the same as "deprecated". As you note, too many authors and organizations depend on this property for it to be simply specced out of existence and removed from implementations.

Perhaps confusion over the meaning of the word "deprecated" is what resulted in the deprecation notice in the first place. The article itself is still incorrectly tagged "Deprecated", by the way.

Note that Mozilla is not responsible for contributions to the MDN docs. The community is. And as with any other community-curated, unofficial knowledge base (including this very site), don't treat its information as gospel, always cross-reference, etc (as you have done here).

Answer (score 1):

Use feature detection. If you need to use feature X, test to see if X is available.

Comment: I know and use feature detection. My question is about the user agent information.

Comment: The user agent string is meaningless; it contains no information. Plenty of letters and numbers, but they're all lies.

Comment: Yes you should not use them for anything too serious. However all major companies I have worked for have used them for example for analytics purposes. I just want to know is it really going away and if so is there a replacement?

Comment: People measure meaningless things all of the time.

Comment: Feature detection doesn't help a lot when dealing with CSS issues, which here in 2022, still is an issue, especially with Safari. Or how Firefox treats REM as another example. In marketing, I wouldn't want to show Apple products to Window users. And Firefox still is not on board with navigator.userAgentData here in Feb 2022. So, we soon will need something for Chromium, and hold on to what we're currently are using for FF and Safari. Then again, how do I know which detection script to use without a detection script?

Answer (score 0):

Feature detection doesn’t always resolve the problems you are confronted with. For instance… Safari does provide html 5 audio, but it implements it in ‘a bad way’. It doesn’t keep the sounds to play in memory as ‘the others’ do. It reloads it when needed. In games sounds have to play immediately when asked, not a second or two too late. Then if you use a extern library that is supposed to solve this problem, Safari is the only one producing a memory leak. So there is no go around there. I would exclude Safari users of using sound in my game, but haven’t found a proper way to detect Safari, for sure.

Comment: I confirm the words of stefcas: For example, Firefox does not support a test on Container Queries, and there is no way around the problem apart from the detection of the user agent. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm the words of stefcas: For example, Firefox does not support a test on Container Queries, and there is no way around the problem apart from the detection of the user agent:

const supportContainerQueries = 'container' in document.documentElement.style

```
// Test support des Container Queries (ok for Chrome, no ok for Firefox)
const isFirefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1 // Fallback test for Firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

On Chrome the [User-Agent string is being deprecated from version 101](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/user-agent-reduction-deprecation-trial/) which is being replaced with [Client Hints](https://wicg.github.io/client-hints-infrastructure/) ([more info](https://http.dev/client-hints)) on Chrome based platforms, though [not currently on Safari or Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-CH#browser_compatibility). You can check the behaviour of your browser by going to [browserleaks.com/client-hints](https://browserleaks.com/client-hints).